# Solving first order non linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve the following first order non-linear differential equation:

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = -\sqrt{\frac{2(\sigma + 1)}{\sigma}} \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2y^{2}} + \frac{1}{8y^{8}}+\frac{3}{4}}
$$

where, $\sigma$ is independent of both x and y. 
After, making use of separable equation, the above equation can be rewritten as:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{8y^8}{6y^8 - 4y^6 + 1}} \partial y = \sqrt{2 \frac {\sigma + 1}{\sigma}} \partial x
$$
Is there any trick that i can use to solve this problem for y ?

Comment: It looks like you had squared both sides, yet did not square the differential terms...

Comment: @user170231 you are right. I edited the question.

Comment: @user170231 No, I have not because i am trying to solve for y(x), where x is independent variable and y is dependent on x in this case. Sorry, I should i have also mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Forget that last suggestion, it doesn't make the problem any easier.

Comment: @user170231 integrating both sides does not make any easier as well, however i reckon it's the only way to go ahead with this problem.